PySpark code that should put new columns in the sql metadatabase automatically to silver = 0, but it's not happening
I have a piece of code that automatically detects new columns from my raw layer and inserts them into the metadatabase in sql server if they don't exist yet. They get put in there with silver = 1 but I have a function that runs at the end of the code that should automatically put it back to silver = 0.
However, this is not happening (silver being put back to 0) and I just can't seem to figure why this is not happening.
Please see my code below:
This is the function that compares the data from the raw object and metadatabase and inserts the new columns into the metadatabase. At the end the function IgnoreInSilver is being called.
#function to insert (new) column names into columnname Metatable
def InsertInto(Source,RawObject):
  # Get all columns in the latest version of the raw object
  sqlStmt = sqlContext.sql(f'SHOW COLUMNS IN raw.{RawObject.lower()}')
  allColumns = sqlStmt.toPandas().iloc[:, 0].values
#   print(len(allColumns))
  
  # Get the columns that are currently in Meta.SelectiveColumnLoading
  Object = mid(RawObject,len(Source)+2,len(RawObject))
  currentColumns = QueryMetaToDataframe("""SELECT [NewColumnName] FROM Meta.SelectiveColumnLoading WHERE [Source] LIKE '{0}' AND [Object] like '{1}'""".format(Source.lower(), Object.lower())) 
  #get ObjectName column
  currentColumnList = currentColumns.toPandas().iloc[:,0].values
#   print(len(currentColumnList))
  
  # Subtract all the columns that are already in Meta.SelectiveColumnLoading
  diff = []
  for col in allColumns:
    if col not in currentColumnList:
      if col not in diff:
        diff.append(col)
  print(str(len(diff)) + " columns need to be added to Meta.SelectiveColumnLoading for " + Object)
  
  for col in diff: # Insert the (new) columns
    InsertStmt = 'INSERT INTO Meta.SelectiveColumnLoading ([Source],[Object],[MergeKey],[OldColumnName],[NewColumnName],[Silver]) VALUES' #start of insert string
    if len(diff) > 0:
      insertedColumns =  []
      insertedColumns.append(diff)
      #temp = col.replace("cxsrec__", "").replace("__c", "") # cleaning unnecessary parts
      #temp = temp.split('_')
      #res = temp[0] + ''.join(sub.title() for sub in temp[1:]) #remove "_"
      res =  col # for now, the oldname is the same as the new name columns, this can change later
      # function to allow for different PK per table per source
      if CheckForMergeKeys(Source.lower(), RawObject.lower(), col) == True:   
        MergeKey = 1
      else:
        MergeKey = 0
      silver = 1
      ObjectName = RawObject.split("_", 1)[1] #.capitalize() # we don't want as a table 'source_table' but just 'Table'
      InsertStmt += """('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}'),""".format(Source,ObjectName,MergeKey,col,res,silver) #add values for each column to insert string
    InsertStmt = InsertStmt[:-1] #remove last comma before inserting
    print(InsertStmt)
    WriteToMeta(InsertStmt)
      # if diff > 0 and not initial run of Object
    if len(diff) > 0 and len(currentColumnList) > 0:
      i = 0  
      for ins in insertedColumns:
        IgnoreInSilver(Source, ins[i], ObjectName)
        i+=1
  return

Here is the small function of ignore in Silver:
def IgnoreInSilver(Source,ColumnName,Object):
    WriteToMeta(f'''UPDATE Meta.SelectiveColumnLoading SET Silver = 0 WHERE Source = '{Source}' and Object = '{Object}' and OldColumnName = '{ColumnName}';''')
    return print('Column: ' + ColumnName + ' will be ignored in the Silver Layer.')

I have tried figuring out why the function IgnoreInSilver isn't executing.

maybe something with autocommit? sql server drivers in python are notorious for not wanting to commit transactions automatically

@siggemannen, what do you mean with autocommit?
